# total number of combinations generated from sample

Tags: r, permutation

I have a vector of 50 number in R and I'm generating permutations of this vector using `sample()` but my question is:

how much is the total number of combinations that can be generated from this vector without repetition??

and does sample calculates the permutations without repetition ??

what i'm doing is like this:

```
for (i in 1:100) 
{
    test$x <- sample(test$x,nrow(test), replace=FALSE)
}
```

is there any possibilities that i might get repetitive permutations from this code for x column ??

Answer (score 1):

1. The number of different permutation should be 50! in your example.
2. Generating samples in sequence does not guarantee uniqueness of them. Try a small example by repeating `sample(1:3)`.
3. Yes, the permutations in your example may repeat.

Answer (score 1):

The number of unique permutations of `n` values is `n!`. If you have, e.g., `n = 3` values, the number of permutations is `3 * 2 * 1 = 6`. In R this number can be calculated with `factorial(n)`.

Different runs of the function `sample` are *independent*. Hence, it is possible to obtain identical permutations.

If you want to generate all permutations of a set of values, you could use the function `permutations` from the `gregmisc` package. Here is an example:

```
# generate a vector of values  
dat <- letters[1:3] # [1] "a" "b" "c"

# the number of values to be drawn from the vector
n_samp <- 2 # Note. The maximum number is: length(dat)

library(gregmisc)

# generate the permutations
permutations(length(dat), n_samp, v = dat)

# The result:

    [,1] [,2]
[1,] "a"  "b" 
[2,] "a"  "c" 
[3,] "b"  "a" 
[4,] "b"  "c" 
[5,] "c"  "a" 
[6,] "c"  "b"
```

Answer (score 0):

As @djurhio mentionned the number of permutations in your example being 50! (i. e. ca. 3e64) is simply too large for you to find all of them. For smaller samples, you can however use function `allPerms` from package `permute`.

```
test<-data.frame(x=round(rnorm(5),2)
test
   x
1  0.33
2  0.34
3  2.18
4  0.92
5 -0.29
library(permute)
t(apply(allPerms(test$x),1,function(X)test$x[X]))
        [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
  [1,]  0.33  0.34  2.18 -0.29  0.92
  [2,]  0.33  0.34  0.92  2.18 -0.29
                    ...
[118,] -0.29  0.92  2.18  0.33  0.34
[119,] -0.29  0.92  2.18  0.34  0.33
```